# Use delegate for Projection in Linq to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have code something like this in an IRepository implementation in Linq to Sql:

```
var newlist = from h in list where h.StringProp1 == "1"
                      select new MyBusinessBO{
                          firstProp = h.StringProp1,
                          secondProp = h.StringProp2
                      };
```

The projection into MyBusinessBO is not difificult but when the Business Object has many properties the projection code becomes very lengthy. Also, as the projection can occur in several places in the Repository we break the DRY principle.

Is there any way to abstract out the projection or replace it with a delegate?

I.e. replace the code

```
                          firstProp = h.StringProp1,
                          secondProp = h.StringProp2
```

with something reusable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Queryable.Select` requires an `Expression<Func<T, U>>`.  You can write a method that returns this and use that method everywhere you do the transformation.

```
public Expression<Func<DataObj, BusiObj>> GetExpr()
{
  return h => new BusiObj()
  {
    firstProp = h.StringProp1,
    secondProp = h.StringProp2
  };
}


 //get a local variable holding the expression.
Expression<Func<DataObj, BusiObj>> toBusiObj = GetExpr();

//use it thusly
var newList = (from h in list where h.StringProp1 == "1" select h)
  .Select(toBusiObj)
  .ToList();

//or
List<BusiObj> newList = list
  .Where(h => h.StringProp1 == "1")
  .Select(toBusiObj)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: A very similar approach to ckknight above, however this looks like it may be better as a means for creating clearer code. It has the projection in a separate re-usable function which can just be passed around. ckknight had the answer but David B, you worked it through in a manner that gets me to where I want to be. I have upvoted ckknight answer and accepted this one.

Comment: Be warned: It is extremely important to use the exact syntax shown here for the `GetExpr()` function . If you have a preexisting DTE conversion method you have used in several places such as `public DTE Convert(Entity entity)` that you are trying to convert to a reusable expression you must REMOVE the `entity` parameter and create the lambda as shown here - otherwise EVERY column in that table will be retrieved.

Answer (score 7):

You could solve this by using the dot syntax rather than the LINQ-style syntax.

Your current:

```
list
    .Where(h => h.StringProp1 == "1")
    .Select(h => new MyBusinessBO
    {
        firstProp = h.StringProp1,
        secondProp = h.StringProp2
    });
```

Potential solution:

```
Func<MyType, MyBusinessBO> selector = h => new MyBusinessBO
{
    firstProp = h.StringProp1,
    secondProp = h.StringProp2
};
list
    .Where(h => h.StringProp1 == "1")
    .Select(selector);
```

And you could pass in the selector somewhere or generate it on-the-fly or something along those lines.

Comment: Nice answer. I would even go one step further and define that `Func` as a real method. The OP wants to reuse that projection logic.

Comment: One consideration before using this answer is that `Func<MyType, MyBusinessBO>` cannot be projected into SQL with Entity Framework. I realize the question is targeting `Linq-to-SQL` which may be able to do the projection, however to write more time-proof code, making your variable be `Expression<Func<MyType, MyBusinessBO>>` could be better.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) and similar tools

Comment: yes, actually already using automapper extensively, in this case it wasn't the best approach

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use regular non-default constructors, rather than object initializers.  Or, if you can start using C# 4.0, try to add optional/default parameters to the mix.